# Subviews are missing when reusing UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a custom cell with the following code on `layoutSubviews`:

```
// Separator Inset
UIImageView *line = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 0.5)];
line.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self addSubview:line];
```

It adds the subview correctly, the problem is when I scroll down and back the subview disappears.

Maybe something to do with reusing the cells, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ExerciciosCell";
    ExerciciosCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[ExerciciosCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

UPDATE:
in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSLog(@"subviews: %d", cell.contentView.subviews.count);` 
NSLog(@"%@", cell.contentView.subviews);
```

Results:

```
"<UILabel: 0x15dca980; frame = (60 12; 248 21); text = 'Supino Reto Na Maquina'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x15dab2c0>>",
    "<UITableViewLabel: 0x15dd1880; frame = (60 32; 248 18); text = 'Peso: 50 - 3x10 reps'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x15dc7410>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x15e91ff0; frame = (0 60; 320 0.5); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15ecaa80>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x15dcc730; frame = (5 5; 50 50); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15db8100>>"
```

Comment: Try calling `[cell setNeedsLayout];` in `cellForRow`

Comment: Log the cell *after* the problem occurs, not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Are you implementing heightForCellAtIndexPath or rowHeight: and setting the height of the cells to 60 or greater so that your line will show? BTW, your if (cell == nil) clause won't ever be entered when you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:, so you should delete that.

Comment: Yes, I have `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, the line does show when `tableview`first loads, it disappear when scroll down and back. Btw, it only disappear on the cells that go away from the screen and come back. So I guess my problem is when I'm reusing the cell.

Comment: If you've added the line in the init method (should be initWithCoder if you made the cell in the storyboard or xib), then that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Exactly. But it is happening. When I log, the line stills there, but it doesn't show. Crazy, huh?

Comment: Are all your other subviews showing as they should after scrolling?

Comment: Yes, but I don't set background color on any of the others. Please see updated question.

Comment: Why would your cells be in the highlighted state when you scroll? That should only happen on selection.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, it didn't log that. But I still can't find the problem.

Comment: it seems subview gets sent to back of view hierarchy when scrolling down and back up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58025/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-jorge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed in my own app, that a line at the very bottom of cells disappears on scrolling if the line's y offset is the same as the height of the cell. If I put the line (a .5 point tall line like yours) 0.5 points above the bottom of the cell, then it doesn't disappear. I'm guessing that this has something to do with the way the table handles the cell separators, so I don't know if there's a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

`layoutSubviews` is called many, many times. It is not the correct place to add a subview. Older image views are being covered by the newer ones.

The right place to add a subview would be in an `init...` method.

Comment: Thanks, should I add the above code on `- (void)awakeFromNib`? The same thing happens though, when I scroll down and back.

Comment: Depends on how you initialise your cell. `initWithStyle:` or `initWithCoder:` maybe. Check the docs for more information.

Comment: `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`

Comment: @Jorge Uh… not sure what you mean by posting that, but yes, one of the two methods, depending on how you initialise your cell.

Comment: Why don't you just add the line to the cell inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath:? like [cell addSubview:line];

Comment: Sorry, we are talking about two different things. For this `tableview` in question I use `initWithCoder`, therefore, I moved the above code to add the subviews in the `init`method. It works. But my problem is, which was the question about, when I scroll down and back the subviews disappear.

Comment: @Jorge Log your cell's subviews when that happens and post the results.

Comment: When I log the subviews in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the subview is there, but it is not showing on the screen. Please see update.

Comment: You should add the subviews for your custom cell in the constructor of that class.

Comment: Please comment on the original question and not here.

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you want to maintain your code in layoutSubviews: How about making a property in your interface like:

```
@interface MyTableViewCell ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *line;

@end
```

Then in your implementation:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (!self.line)
    {
        self.line = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 0.5)];
        self.line.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self addSubview:self.line];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not add subviews in `layoutSubviews`.